# How to interpret values of elevation standard deviation statistic (and not elevation mean) from DEM

Tags: dem, elevation, slope, topography, modelling

I am trying to interpret the standard deviation of elevation to understand the topographic landform of my study area.

We have 2km*2km grids in the study area for which we extracted certain landscape features including elevation,  slope, aspect etc using DEM data sourced from ALOS World 3D 30m. In my information-criteria based analysis, variables like 'elevation standard deviation' (and not the mean statistic of elevation) is coming out to be a significant predictor.

I am trying to understand what this tells about the characteristic of the landscape at the spatial scale of 2km*2km. Does it indicate the steepness of the area (or grid)? And shouldn't steepness be reliably indicated by the 'slope' variable instead?
Moreover, the elevation standard deviation variable and the slope (mean) variable are significantly correlated. So, is it acceptable to interchange their use in analysis, (if at all the interpretation is same)?